# How can i change the area according to the country in android app?

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have two spinner.one is located at the toolbar that represent the country and other is located at the fragment that represent the area.i am getting data from the server i want to do that when i select the country that particular area is shown in the area spinner.

This is my json data

```
    {
      "Status": 1,
      "StatusMessage": "Country and Country Area List",
      "data": [
        {
          "CountryID": "1",
          "CountryName": "India",
          "CountryArea": [
            {
              "CountryID": "1",
              "AreaID": "1",
              "AreaName": "Kuwait City(Capital)"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "1",
              "AreaID": "2",
              "AreaName": " Hawally"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "1",
              "AreaID": "3",
              "AreaName": "Farwaniya"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "1",
              "AreaID": "4",
              "AreaName": "  Ahmadi"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "1",
              "AreaID": "5",
              "AreaName": " Jahra"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "CountryID": "2",
          "CountryName": "Dubai",
          "CountryArea": [
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "6",
              "AreaName": " Jeddah"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "7",
              "AreaName": " Riyadh"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "8",
              "AreaName": " Khobar"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "9",
              "AreaName": " Abha"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "10",
              "AreaName": " Abqiq"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "11",
              "AreaName": " Abu Arish"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "12",
              "AreaName": " Al Ahsa"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "13",
              "AreaName": " Al Baha"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "14",
              "AreaName": " Al Dhahran"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "15",
              "AreaName": " Al Jubail"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "16",
              "AreaName": " Al Kharj"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "17",
              "AreaName": " Al Madina El Monawara"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "18",
              "AreaName": " Al Qatif"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "19",
              "AreaName": " Al Taif"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "20",
              "AreaName": " Almadnab"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "21",
              "AreaName": " Bisha"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "22",
              "AreaName": " Buraida"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "23",
              "AreaName": " Dawadmy"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "24",
              "AreaName": " Hafr Elbatin"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "25",
              "AreaName": " Hail "
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "26",
              "AreaName": " Jazan"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "27",
              "AreaName": " Mecca"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "28",
              "AreaName": " Oniza"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "29",
              "AreaName": " Qurayat"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "30",
              "AreaName": " Zulfi"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "31",
              "AreaName": "Dammam"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

This is my CountryAdpter which is located at the Toolbar:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        this.menu = menu;
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner).setVisible(true);
        mCountrySpinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);


        countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mCountryList);
        countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);

        mCountrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                countryId = getCountryId.get(position);
                Log.e("countryid", countryId);


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: And where is your spinner code?

Answer (score 0):

I will outline the general steps you need to go through in order the construct your data in a proper way.

**1st.** You need to parse the given JSON. I **highly** recommend using a library like **GSON**. It's easy to use and it's really helpful. In order to pass it by using GSON, you must create at least two classes - **Country** and **CountryArea**. The class Country should have a list of CountryArea objects. Make sure the variable names mach **completely** the corresponding key from the JSON, or use the **SerializedName** property of GSON.

**2nd.** When you hit **onItemSelected** populate the second Spinner in the same way you had populated the first one, but with the corresponding Country Areas this time.

Comment: i already suggested OP to use `countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Country>` instead of `countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>` but he just ignored that, so probably using GSON and those two POJO classes will not be accepted by him

Comment: i accepted your answer but i don't know how can i use this procedure. i made Country class and save data in it. but there is no change.@pskink